# Cannot exclude a auto generated column of a Table using Django ModelForm

Tags: python, django

I am using Django and oracle as backend. I have a table 'Orders' and it has  a column 'order_id' as primary key which is also set to auto generate Ids in Oracle. Now I am using a Model Form 'OrderForm' for adding and updating orders.

Now the problem is when I try to add a new order, then it throw error saying 'cannot insert in to a generated always identity column'.

How can I avoid the column 'order_id' which is auto generated field and update the remaining fields alone. I tried omit 'order_id' from model, It doesn't throw error, but now it does not create record in DB .

I am new to Django..Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To exclude the auto-generated identity column ('order_id') when using a Django ModelForm for creating and updating orders with an Oracle database, you can use the exclude attribute in the Meta class of the form.

forms.py file

```
from django import forms
from .models import Order

class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        exclude = ['order_id']

#This OrderForm will automatically exclude the 'order_id' field, allowing you to 
#create and update orders without specifying the identity column.
```

views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import OrderForm

def create_order(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save()  # Creates a new order without specifying 'order_id'
            return redirect('success_page')  # Redirect to success page
    else:
        form = OrderForm()

    return render(request, 'create_order.html', {'form': form})
```

when the form is submitted and valid, form.save() is called, and Django creates a new order without specifying the 'order_id' field, allowing the database to handle its auto-generation. Rearrange the code as per your requirement.

Comment: I already tried this. But this will only exclude it from the form that is posted in your page. When I try to save the form, it try to insert 'Null' in to order_id field in the database. That is the issue. I want it to completely ignor order_id field even when trying to save the form data.  Thanks for replying.

Comment: Can you show your model representation?

Comment: Sorry @Kapil. Actually your code is working fine when table is created through model 'Manage=True'. But My problem is that, I already have a existing table with data (legacy DB) which have one field as gererated column. I created model with 'Manage=False' for this existing table 'Order'. In this scenario this is not working. That is the issue.